# USB A male to USB A male connection

Tags: usb

I have a digital music player having songs in its internal hard drive. It also has an external USB port to play songs from USB flash disks. Can I use this port to transfer files (songs) from internal hard drive to my computer using USB A male to male connector?

Comment: This will be closed because questions about the *usage* of consumer electronics are not electronic *design* questions.  As a practical matter it is impossible to say, without knowing the capabilities of the music player.  In most cases however the answer would be "no".

Comment: Have you ever seen an A-to-A cable? I haven't. I don't think they exist, and the reason is that I don't think two USB A ports can connect together in any way supported by the USB specification.

Comment: Two USB A host ports cannot talk to each other. See USB spec on usb.org for details.

Comment: @mkeith: i have a few, they do make them. I think your right about them not being under any spec. Mine came with an external  USB hard drive enclosure...

Comment: unless it came with said cable, 99% "no".

Comment: This sounds like a superuser question all the way, unless you make it about designing and building an active adapter?

Answer (score 2):

If your music player reads files from USB flash drives, it means that it acts as USB Host. Your PC is also a USB host. Two USB classic hosts can't talk to each other, so the answer to your question is "no".

A classic Type-A USB host must supply voltage on VBUS pin of USB receptacle. There are A-A plug cables, but they are illegal in USB framework, because an unsophisticated user can try to connect two hosts, and their voltages may conflict possibly causing excessive current. For this reason A-A cables are prohibited by standard.

Before small (micro and mini) USB receptacle were introduced, some manufacturers of portable USB hard drives used to make enclosures with Type-A receptacle on HDD, because the standard Type-B port is too big to their taste. In this case they would supply a dedicated A-A cable, frequently with Y-connector, to use an adjacent USB port and increase current supply to HDD (because at early ages the 2.5" HDD were quite power hungry). This is all in the past now.